# Ubercart - add comment pane text to order template

Tags: 7, theming, ubercart

In Ubercart pane settings I turned on comment pane (at admin/store/settings/checkout), that is displayed at checkout page. I'm also overriding default order template an I need to print the comment here. Is it possible to achieve that without modifying ubercart module?